# Why since() and until() methods dont work properly on Facebook API Graph?

Tags: python, python-3.x, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I am getting the data and insgihts from the post of a certain Facebook page like this:

```
node = '/' + page_id +'?fields=posts.limit(100).since(' + str(since) + ').until(' + str(until) + '){id,link,created_time,message,type,permalink_url,'+'insights.metric('+['Array of metrics']+').period(lifetime)}'
url = base + node
parameters = {'access_token': token, 'limit': '100'}
object1 = requests.get(url, params=parameters).text.encode('utf-8')
```

This works as expected but only if i ask for recent dates, if i want to get the post of a certain day 7 days ago or more, it starts sampling.
I try using the [API Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) but it gives me the same result as my code. I use Unixtime as Facebook ask for.

> Does anyone know why fb API graph does this "Sampling"?

Comment: What do you mean by “sampling” …?

Comment: By sampling i mean that instead of showing me all the post of that day it only gives back just a few, this is what [sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_%28statistics%29) means